# How to change base directory properly in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

I am using xampp. I use to work under htdocs/Admin so my RewriteBase was `RewriteBase /Admin/`. However, I had to move under htdocs/company/Admin, and this messed all of my .htaccess rules i guess. How can I fix this issue.
My .htaccess looks like this.

```
Options -indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Admin/
RewriteRule ^liste/(.*)$ index.php?sayfa=liste&tablo=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^modul-ekle$ index.php?sayfa=modul-ekle [NC]
RewriteRule ^ekle/(.*)$ index.php?sayfa=ekle&tablo=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^duzenle/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?sayfa=duzenle&tablo=$1&ID=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^sil/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?sayfa=sil&tablo=$1&ID=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^anasayfa$ index.php?sayfa=anasayfa [NC]
...
...
```

I tried to change my RewriteBase with `RewriteBase company/Admin` and that didn't work.
Do I have to change the paths in all of my PHP files or are there any ways of doing this with a single change in my .htaccess code?

Thanks!

Comment: `company/Admin` and `company/admin` are two different things on unixoid systems. Their file systems are case sensitive...

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying that part but directory names are the same for case sensitivity perspective I just forgot to type it in my question. I am editing right now!

Comment: You still have the same discrepancy in your question... "I had to move under htdocs/company/admin" versus "my RewriteBase with RewriteBase company/Admin". That does _not_ match, sorry.

Comment: /company/Admin actually worked in my case I just had to fix some paths in my php code. Thanks anyways

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Ah, I see, now you indeed updated your question and the spelling matches.

Comment: @MrWhite Yes I did, I wasn't using .htaccess for all the redirections, I had to change themn in my php code other than that changing 'RewriteBase /Admin/' with 'RewriteBase /company/Admin/' worked just fine